# Chatbox text escapping <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, chat

Right now i want to create a fake "chat" feature. problem now is that when i click "send" over and over again the text escapes the div. is there a way to make it so that when the text in the div is nearing the div border it will stop or make a scrolling feature. 
I only can use Html Javascript and CSS

```js
  function postchat(){
  var node =document.createElement("p");
  var content= document.getElementById("comment").value;
  var comment= content;
  var textnode = document.createTextNode(comment);
  node.appendChild(textnode);
  document.getElementById("allComment").appendChild(node);
 }
```

```css
#chatbox {
width:50%;
    text-align:left;
 background-color:#F7F7F7;
    height:250px;
 border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="chatbox">     
<div id="allComment" style="font-size:10px; line-height:90%;" ></div>
</div>
<p>
<input type="text" id="comment"></input>
</p>
<input type="button" value="Send" onclick="postchat()" />
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you make the scrollbars: `overflow-y: scroll;` - see below.

I cant replicate the described behaviour on multiple clicks on send - could you elaborate?

```js
  function postchat(){
  var node =document.createElement("p");
  var content= document.getElementById("comment").value;
  var comment= content;
  var textnode = document.createTextNode(comment);
  node.appendChild(textnode);
  document.getElementById("allComment").appendChild(node);
 }
```

```css
#chatbox {
width:50%;
    text-align:left;
 background-color:#F7F7F7;
    height:250px;
 border:1px solid black;
overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="chatbox">     
<div id="allComment" style="font-size:10px; line-height:90%;" ></div>
</div>
<p>
<input type="text" id="comment"></input>
</p>
<input type="button" value="Send" onclick="postchat()" />
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `overflow:auto`

```js
function postchat(){
  var node =document.createElement("p");
  var content= document.getElementById("comment").value;
  var comment= content;
  var textnode = document.createTextNode(comment);
  node.appendChild(textnode);
  document.getElementById("allComment").appendChild(node);
 }
```

```css
#chatbox {
width:50%;
    text-align:left;
    background-color:#F7F7F7;
    height:250px;
    border:1px solid black;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="chatbox">     
<div id="allComment" style="font-size:10px; line-height:90%;" ></div>
</div>
<p>
<input type="text" id="comment"></input>
</p>
<input type="button" value="Send" onclick="postchat()" />
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need `overflow:auto` this will not allow the p tag to overflow the container.

```
#chatbox {
    width:50%;
    text-align:left;
    background-color:#F7F7F7;
    height:250px;
    border:1px solid black;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `overflow: auto;` on your CSS for `#chatbox`, so when the text will be over the content of your div, the scroll bar will appear on your `#chatbox`.

[More info about overflow here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow).

`overflow: auto;` will detect automatically overflow for `X` and `Y`.

```js
  function postchat(){
  var node =document.createElement("p");
  var content= document.getElementById("comment").value;
  var comment= content;
  var textnode = document.createTextNode(comment);
  node.appendChild(textnode);
  document.getElementById("allComment").appendChild(node);
 }
```

```css
#chatbox {
width:50%;
    text-align:left;
 background-color:#F7F7F7;
    height:250px;
 border:1px solid black;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="chatbox">     
<div id="allComment" style="font-size:10px; line-height:90%;" ></div>
</div>
<p>
<input type="text" id="comment"></input>
</p>
<input type="button" value="Send" onclick="postchat()" />
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using either `overflow:auto` or `overflow-y:scroll` should work for you.

`overflow: auto` will scroll in all directions if necessary, while `overflow-y: scroll` will keep the scrolling to just the vertical (y) axis.

```css
#chatbox {
width:50%;
    text-align:left;
    background-color:#F7F7F7;
    height:250px;
    border:1px solid black;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    /*  overflow: auto */
}
```